# Custom button to Approve/Reject

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-button, approval-process

Currently, to approve or reject an application, user need to click this highlighted button from image (1), then it will redirect user to page image (2). User need to click highlighted text to go to approval page image (3). Button from image (1) is not a standard page. It is URL. Highlighted text from image (2) is from flows, and page image (3) is a approval process. What I want is, once user click on highlighted button from page image (1), it will bring user to page image (3). May I know how to do that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create a custom button field, choose onclick javascript as content source. Then you can paste this code. Change according to your requirement.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE processInstance.TargetObjectId='{!objectName__c.Id}'");
var approvals = result.getArray("records");

if(approvals != undefined && approvals.length > 0)
{
var approvalID = approvals[0].Id;
window.open('/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id='+approvalID);
}
else
{
alert("There are no approvals pending.")
}
```